# Not able to understand Lambda -> operator

Tags: android, lambda, rx-java2

I have copied a code from net which uses Lambda operator. Following is the code.

```
  Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .zipWith(listObj, (time, item) -> item)
```

I am trying to learn rxJava , and cannot get how this lambda function is working, that is how those time and item variables are functioning ?

If I open the zipwith() method in internal docs, then following is how it is

```
 @SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
public final <U, R> Observable<R> zipWith(Iterable<U> other,  BiFunction<? super T, ? super U, ? extends R> zipper) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(other, "other is null");
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(zipper, "zipper is null");
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableZipIterable<T, U, R>(this, other, zipper));
}
```

Now my list obj is arraylist of strings .So can someone tell me how are these arguments mapping exactly with the method using Lambda operator , rather can anyone tell me how to write the same without using lambda operator ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RX's `Zip` operator combines multiple observables through a function.
In your context, you have 2 observables, one that emits `Long` values and the second one `String` values.

The lambda `(time, item) -> item` refers to a function that accepts two values and returns the second one. Types are inferred from the observables, namely `Long` and `String`.

Here's the same code without lambda (and using Rx2):

```
Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .zipWith(listObj, new BiFunction<Long, String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(Long time, String item) throws Exception {
                    return item;
                }
            });
```

In case you need to use Rx1, instead of using `BiFunction` you have to use `Func2`.

Answer (score 4):

Lambda operator specifies an [anonymous function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). It's a function without a name and just contains the parameters and the "body". If we take for example your lambda function `(time, item) -> item`. It accepts two parameters, `time` and `item` and returns the `item`. The accepted function for `zipWith()` is specified as

> [zipFunction](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/index.html?rx/Observable.html) - a function that combines the pairs of items from the Observable and the Iterable to generate the items to be emitted by the resulting Observable

In your case it will accept the current `time` from the interval and an `item` from your `listObj`. Then you lambda function decides how you combine these two into what the `Observable` will  `emitt`.

A simple example for using `lambda` would look like this:

```
String[] presets = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "CA"};

// Find all matching
List<String> resultList = Arrays.stream(presets)
                                .filter(x -> x.startsWith("C"))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

We basically filter the contents of the `array` named `presets` based on the `lambda` function `x -> x.startsWith("C")`. This means it will iterate through the array, take the element (`x`) and return a `true` or `false` based on a condition. In this case it will filter those `Strings` that start with `C`.

Your example without the `lambda`, using Anonymous classes in `RxJava1`. For `RxJava2` you need to use `BiFunction` instead of `Func2`.

```
  Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .zipWith(listObj, new Func2<Integer, String, String>() {
      public String call(Integer value1, String value2) {
                return value2 + String.valueOf(value2);
      }
  });
```

This would take your `time` and concatenate it with the current `item` in the `listObj`.

Comment: Hey awesome and thanks, so you mean the value I put as 5 is automatically considered in "time" parameter ???